# Dynamically adding one layout to another

Tags: android, layout, onclick

I'm new to android, and I'm trying to dynamically add 1 layout below another. I've already seen similar questions & answers before but I can't seem to find my way. I hope someone can clear things for me.

I have main layout (import_custom_fields) to which I want to add second layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/import_custom_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp">

        <FrameLayout
         android:clickable="true"   
         android:id="@+id/profile_picture_frame"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         android:foreground="@drawable/selector">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ProfilePicture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_picture_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_picture_size"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/menu_profile_picture_header"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/addPlus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/menu_profile_picture_add"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:src="@drawable/plus" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_picture_frame"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/FirstNameEdit"
                android:tag="@string/vcard_tag_first_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                android:hint="@string/first_name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
                android:lines="1"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/LastNameEdit"
                android:tag="@string/vcard_tag_last_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                android:hint="@string/last_name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
                android:lines="1" />  
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

second layout (fields_to_inflate):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fields_to_inflate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >    

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerPhone"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinnerPhone"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinnerPhone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, my activity looks like this:

```
public class ImportCustomFields extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.import_custom_fields);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerPhone);
        ImageView addField = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.add);
        addField.setClickable(true);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                                                                             R.array.custom_fields,
                                                                             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        final LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.import_custom_fields);
        final RelativeLayout inflateLayout = (RelativeLayout)View.inflate(this, R.layout.fields_to_inflate, null);

        addField.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mainLayout.addView(inflateLayout);  
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm getting null exception error @ this line ( mainLayout.addView(inflateLayout) ).

Comment: thanks and sorry i forgot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the id of the layout that you assigned:

```
final LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.import_custom_field);
```